# Prevent subview from scrolling in a UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, scroll, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` subclass with a certain subview I'd like to prevent from scrolling (while all the other subviews scroll as normal).

The closest example to this I can think of is `UITableView`'s "index strip" on the right side (look in the Contacts app to see an example). I am guessing this is a subview of the table (scrollview) but it does not move as the user scrolls.

I can't seem to make my subview stay put! How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is to adjust the frame of the "non-scrollable" subview inside `-layoutSubviews`.

Comment: -(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.label.x = CONTENT_OFFSET + self.contentOffset.x;
}

Comment: Why does setting the frame in `layoutSubviews` make the subviews not scrollable?

Answer (score 2):

Add the view that you want not to move as a sibling view of the scroll view on top of the scroll view instead of as a subview.

Comment: Agreed, if you do not want it to be scrolled, simply remove it from the subview and add as an additional subview with a proper frame.

Answer (score -2):

You can set it's property called userInteractionEnabled to NO

Comment: No. This will stop the entire scrollview from scrolling. Instead, I'm trying to stop *one* of the scrollview's subviews from moving while everything else scrolls.