# Disable Subview of UITableview from Scrolling

Tags: xcode, uitableview, scroll, subview

(xCode 4.3.2, ARC, Storyboard) I have a Master/Detail project and the MasterViewController is a UITableViewController, as usual. It has a navigation bar at the top and a toolbar at the bottom. I've created a custom subview that I load programmatically in `viewDidLoad`.

It loads fine, and is on top just like I want, but when the user scrolls the tableview, the subview scrolls too. I need the subview to "stick" to the bottom.

[image]

**Here is the code I used to add the subview:**

```
    CGRect totalFrame = CGRectMake(0, 314, 320, 58);
    UIView *totalBG = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:totalFrame];
    totalBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"totalBG.png"]];
    [self.view addSubview:totalBG];

    CGRect totalLabelFrame = CGRectMake(12, 12, 80, 40);
    totalLabelBG = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:totalLabelFrame];
    totalLabelBG.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    totalLabelBG.text = @"Total:";
    [totalLabelBG setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:22]];
    totalLabelBG.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    totalLabelBG.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    totalLabelBG.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    totalLabelBG.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    [totalBG addSubview:totalLabelBG];
```

I tried setting userInteractionEnabled to NO in `viewDidLoad` and detecting a
touch, and setting the `totalLabelBG.center` property, and neither worked.

I've also read through a lot of threads on disabling scrolling for webviews, but found nothing relevant.

I found another SOF question with a response that may or may not work, but the user did not explain the answer. ["The trick is to adjust the frame of the "non-scrollable" subview inside -layoutSubviews."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011076/prevent-subview-from-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 10):

I achieved the desired result by adding the subview to the `UINavigationController` container like this:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:totalBG];
```

Answer (score 0):

Like in the answer above. Just add that particular subview to any subview outside on the UIScrollView instance. If its not suppose to scroll then it doesn't make sense to put it inside the scroll view to begin with. Instead make the scroll view only take up the height up to the top of the totals subview